# How to get an index of specific element ina ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListView` of images and checkboxes alternating elements (image, checkbox, image, etc).

When I use `Thumbnails.SelectedIndex`, it returns the element position, but I want the element position only for images and to have checkboxes ignored.

How to do this?

```
private void Thumbnails_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int item = Thumbnails.SelectedIndex + 1; //get original index for each element in ListView
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(item));
}
```

Comment: HI, welcome to the Stack! Please review this page for how to use this site effectively http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Show a bit how your thing is structured, i could help us understand your issue.

Comment: @user1394252 show us a bit of your XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this. On my side I can see it display the index only for images. Let me know if u face problem.

```
    private void Thumbnails_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        int item = Thumbnails.SelectedIndex + 1; //get original index for each element in ListView

        object content = Thumbnails.SelectedItem;
        if (content is Image)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(item));
        }



    }
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. However, I need checkbox elements to be completely ignored if possible. Right now, for pictures, I get odd numbers 1,3,5,7....but I want those odd positions to be considered as 1,2,3,4....is this also possible

Comment: You mean you want a running sequence of integers for images is it? From what I get from your question, basically if u have 4 images in your listview you expect output as 1 2 3 4 always (assuming u have alternate image and check box only)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Thats straight forward. The first time u detect an image u know the starting index for image and u can store it globally and for every subsequent image just increment this variable and display it instead of item

Comment: Oh, yes but I actually need the item displayed. It's a long story why, but I need for example 3rd item to be considered as 2nd item, and then 5th item to be considered as 3rd item and so on.....generally, I need something that will map odd items into subsequent items.

Comment: I am totally confused.Your initial question was something different. Anyways cant you than just not decrement the item by 1 and display